# Not recognized by the 'identify' command error while using validates_each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-2, paperclip-validation

Below is my validations for image content type which works fine.

```
validates_attachment_size :icon, :less_than => MAX_SIZE.megabytes, :message => "Max size is 1 mb"
validates_attachment_content_type :icon, :content_type => ['image/jpg','image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
```

**BUT**

I need to validate the dimensions also and my code is

```
validates_each :icon do |record, attr, value|
    if record.icon_file_name
       dimensions = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(value.queued_for_write[:original])
       if(dimensions.width > 600 || dimensions.height > 400)
         record.errors.add(:file, " #{record.icon_file_name} dimensions must be less than or equal to 600*400")
       end
     end
   end
```

**AND**

*it gives imagemagick error `Not recognized by the 'identify' command error`*

Can you put some light on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using "validate" method instead of "validates_each"
http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/33-how-to-write-custom-validation-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not have ImageMagick installed on your machine. If you do, type

> which identify

and add the path as value to the following paperclip option in `environment.rb`

> Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/" #assuming this folder

Let know how it goes..

Answer (score 0):

Finally, did with the help of yours input.

```
validate :icon_dimensions
```

```
def icon_dimensions
  unless icon.to_file.nil?
    dimensions = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(icon.to_file(:original))
    if(dimensions.width > 72 || dimensions.height > 72)
      errors.add(:icon, " dimensions must be less than or equal to 72*72")
    end
  end
end
```

I hope the validates_each executed before or override the other validations. Not sure :(